# jQuery TwoWay Data Binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding

How do you implement a simple two-way data binding in jQuery?
Something like knockoutJS, but in the simplest possible form.

Scenario - bind JSON object to table row (every field is **td>input/>/td>**).

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should give a more specific example and some tries.

Comment: I did. Check my own answer. Any suggestions, tricks?

Comment: http://jquerymy.com/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My try - HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Data Binding</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="content-table">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="get-data">Get</button>
    <button id="set-data">Set</button>

    <script src="../js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/vendor/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/vendor/watch.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/dataBinder.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var DataBinder = (function ($) {

    var _$table = null,
        _objectList = [],
        _fieldList = [],
        _objectListLength = -1,
        _fieldListLength = -1;

    /* AJAX call or smth. */
    var _loadData = function () {
        var fakeData = [{
            name: 'John',
            surname: 'Doe'
        }, {
            name: 'Foo',
            surname: 'Bar'
        }];

        _objectList = $.map(fakeData, function (element, index) {
            var elementObject = {
                _dataBinderId: index,
                element: element,
                input: {}
            };

            watch(elementObject.element, function (property, action, newValue) {
                _setValue.call(elementObject, property, newValue);
            });

            return elementObject;
        });

        _objectListLength = _objectList.length;
    };

    var _getFields = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < _objectListLength; i++) {
            for (var field in _objectList[i].element) {
                if (!!!~$.inArray(field, _fieldList)) {
                    _fieldList.push(field);
                }
            }
        }

        _fieldListLength = _fieldList.length;
    };

    var _setValue = function (field, value) {
        this.input[field].val(value);
    };

    var _bindEvents = function () {
        $('#get-data').on('click', function () {
            alert(JSON.stringify(_getRowData()));
        });

        $('#set-data').on('click', function () {
            _objectList[0].element.name = 'PIPA';
            _objectList[1].element.surname = 'BLAAAAAAH';
        });

        _$table.on('keyup', 'input', function () {
            var $this = $(this), field = $this.data('field'), source = $this.closest('tr').data('source');
            source[field] = $this.val();
        });
    };

    var _getRowData = function () {
        var elements = [];

        $.each(_objectList, function () {
            elements.push(this.element);
        });

        return elements;
    };

    var _generateEditableElements = function () {
        var rowList = [], headerRow = $('<tr>');

        for (var k = 0; k < _fieldListLength; k++) {
            headerRow.append($('<th>', {
                text: _fieldList[k].toUpperCase()
            }));
        }
        _$table.find('thead').append(headerRow);

        for (var i = 0; i < _objectListLength; i++) {
            var objectData = _objectList[i], currentRow = $('<tr>');

            currentRow.data('source', objectData.element);
            rowList.push(currentRow);

            for (var j = 0; j < _fieldListLength; j++) {
                var field = _fieldList[j], $inputElement = $('<input>', {
                    type: 'text',
                    value: objectData.element[field]
                });

                $inputElement.data('field', field);
                objectData.input[field] = $inputElement;

                currentRow.append($('<td>').append($inputElement));
            }
        }

        _$table.find('tbody').append(rowList);
    };

    var init = function ($table) {
        _$table = $table;

        _loadData();
        _getFields();

        _generateEditableElements();
        _bindEvents();
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };

})(jQuery);

DataBinder.init($("#content-table"));
```

[image: Result]

I've used amazing [Watch.JS](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS). [How Does Watch.js Work?](http://dailyjs.com/2012/11/12/code-review-watch-js/)

[Watch.js now uses Object.observe](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS/commit/d29b7e4931430d117cacee4e5badc0f2e13c4d8a)

Here is another example [Easy Two-Way Data Binding in JavaScript](http://www.lucaongaro.eu/blog/2012/12/02/easy-two-way-data-binding-in-javascript/).

And another [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904039/plain-javascript-bidirectional-data-binding)

[Native JavaScript Data-Binding](http://www.sellarafaeli.com/blog/native_javascript_data_binding).

Comment: Watch.JS looks nice, but it uses setInterval for periodic checks. That can't be good for performance...

Comment: Now it uses Object.observe if present.

Comment: Awesome! I'm looking forward to testing Watch.js in light of this new feature!

Comment: Isnt that possible with Jquery delegate { on() } as well ?

Comment: Best question and answer I've seen in years!

Answer (score 4):

This solution is pretty simple, and it can be extended to have a more complex functionality: http://cssshowcase.co.uk/two-way-data-binding-with-jquery/

It literally binds 2 or more HTML elements together, with it's current form it changes the inner html of any element and the value of any input as well, for each element that holds the same "bind" attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

This below jQuery code working seems like two way binding in angularJs

```
<script purpose="Setting value for total cost">
    $(document).ready(()=>{ 
        var sumTotalCost = () => {
            var val1 = +$("#base_salary").val();
            var val2 = +$("#on_cost").val();
            $("#total_cost").val(val1 + val2);
        }
        $(".sumtotal-elements").keyup(function () {
            sumTotalCost()
        });
    })
</script>

<input class="form-control sumtotal-elements" type="text" name='base_salary'id="base_salary">

<input class="form-control sumtotal-elements" type="text" name='on_cost' id="on_cost">

<input class="form-control" type="text" name='total' id="total_cost" >
```