# How to bind a object to update the value using plain js?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a object with name value. Is it possible to bind that value to html element? - like `angularjs`

if so what is the correct way? or is it not possible?

here is my demo :

```js
var ob = {};

ob.name = "Testing";

$('div').text(ob.name);

$('button').on('click', function(){

 ob.name = "Update Name";
  
  console.log( ob.name ) //name updates

})
```

```css
button{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1></h1> <!-- on click nothing updates automatically -->
</div>
<button>Click Here</button>
```

Comment: `$('div').text(ob.name);` will update the text..You do not have that in click handler.. You are looking for something like `two-way-binding` but it does not happen on its own!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483560/how-to-implement-dom-data-binding-in-javascript

Comment: the answer from Rajesh helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript allows the creation of object "properties" where reading or writing can execute user-defined code.

What you can do is creating the HTML node and a Javascript object with a property so that when you write to the property the code updates the HTML node:

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(d);
var obj = {get value()  { return d.textContent; },
           set value(x) { d.textContent = x; }};
obj.value = "foo"; // Will also update d content
```

Note that a property that allows writing needs a place where to store the data... in the above I used directly `d.textContent` so the two are actually synchronized (changing `obj.value` changes the DOM node and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript itself doesnt support bidirectionalBinding from scratch.

To make your example work simply add the expression, that you have already figured out correct, to your onClickFunction.

```js
var ob = {};

ob.name = "Testing";
$('div').text(ob.name);


$('button').on('click', function(){

 ob.name = "Update Name";
        $('div').text(ob.name); <!-- add here -->
  
  console.log( ob.name ) //name updates

})
```

```css
button{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1></h1> 
</div>
<button>Click Here</button>
```

> Just to clarify! It is possible to implement something that you could
>   call bidirectionalBinding, but thats not what you want to do using
>   plain javascript! It would mean implementing eventListeners on your
>   textValue etc.

Comment: the question look like to bid the data. the one you given the idea is not connected to his question

Comment: @3gwebtrain I am having trouble in understanding you. Is there something wrong about my answer?