# Dynamically Change variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var x = [];

$('input').click(function(){
  $(this.value).push('Hello'); //x.push('Hello');
  alert(x) //Expected Result: 'Hello'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='x'>
```

I want to push the value `Hello` to the local variable array with the identifier equal to that of the value of the button that was clicked. For example, if the button with the `value="x"` is clicked, I want `var x = ...` to be updated. Similarly, if `value="y"` is clicked, `var y = ...` should be updated.

Is that possible?

Comment: lol[...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483560/how-to-implement-dom-data-binding-in-javascript#16484266)

Comment: I'm not at all clear on what it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: @j08691 Updated the question to better explain what the OP is trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that would be to use an object to contain your variables. By default, the `window` object is used, but that is bad practice. You can wrap the variables yourself, like so:

```js
var values = {
  x: [],
  y: [],
  z: []
};

$('input').click(function(){
  values[this.value].push('Hello'); //x.push('Hello');
  alert(values[this.value]) //Expected Result: 'Hello'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='x'>
<input type='button' value='y'/>
<input type='button' value='z'/>
```

Comment: Wouldn't a multi dimensional array work too? giving it a key name of the `value`

Comment: @Toleo I suppose it could, but you'd have to have some sort of map that said `[0]` was for `x` and `[1]` was for `y`, etc. Or you'd have to have a key/value array and nest your arrays multiple levels deep. It's doable, but highly unnecessary. Using an object is the correct way to do this.

Comment: @Toleo There are numerous ways, [here are a few](https://repl.it/@ugam44/MajesticBoldFunction)

Comment: @Toleo Depends on JS engine. You can look at perf tests, or [this SO question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/how-do-i-empty-an-array-in-javascript), but with less than several hundred thousand iterations, the difference is too negligible to worry about.