# Bind HTML element to Javascript object and store object in array - Update object with input value from child element

Tags: javascript

In vanilla JavaScript how can I bind an element to an object so that if a child element of the object has a value I can update the object with it? Need to be compatible with IE10+ and all other browsers.

With a button I am dynamically adding an element (`createElement()`) containing a form input. When the element is created it also creates an object that should also be the element so I can update the object with the input value on change.

I then store each new object in an array.

The issue I am having is connecting the input value with the correct object. I tried looping through the array hoping to update each object in turn with the current input value of the event target but couldn't succeed. I tried registering the element (deprecated) and various other things but I cannot quite workout how to link the input to the container object (lineObject).

I could really use some help solving this problem and understanding how to bind an element to an object in the way I need.

```js
//lineNumber *** // 
let lineNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.lineNumber');
let numberOfLines = lineNumber.length;
//first instance of input element
let lineText = document.querySelector('.lineText');
//first input value of element
let lineTextValue = document.querySelector('input[name="lineText"]').value;
//create initial lineObject for first line
let lastLine = lineNumber[numberOfLines - 1];
let lineContainer;

//lineNumber object constructor
function LineObject(lineText, writable) {
 //set properties
 this.lineText = lineText;
 this.writable = writable;
} 

//new object at new lineNumber element, set values
let lineObject = new LineObject(lineTextValue, true);

//create array containing initial line object
let lineArray = [lineObject];

//line functions
(function lineGeneration(){

  //add or remove lines
  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

   //this
   let self = e.target;

   // has class .addLine
   if (hasClass(self, 'addLine')) {
    
    //call function to get variables
    insertLineHTML();
        
    //clone new line after the last line\
    self.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.appendChild(lineObject.cloneNode(true));

        //lineNumber input location
        let newlineTextInput = self.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.querySelector('input[name="lineText"]');
    
    //input value of new element
        let lineTextValue = newlineTextInput.value;//normally "" when created unless placeholder text
    
    //new object at new lineNumber element
        lineObject = new LineObject(lineTextValue, true);
    
        //add new object to lineArray
        lineArray.push(lineObject);
    
    refreshLineNodeList();
  
   } 

 }); 

    //combine accordion / refresh
    function refreshLineNodeList(){

          //refresh number of elements in nodelist
          lineNumber = document.querySelectorAll('.lineNumber');

          //get new length
          numberOfLines = lineNumber.length; 

        }

    //line html and vars
    function insertLineHTML(){
        lineObject = document.createElement('div');
        lineObject.setAttribute('class', 'lineNumber');
        lineObject.innerHTML = ` 
            <div class="accordion-title">
            <h3>Line 2</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="input-section"> 

            <div class="input-row">

            <div class="input-container">
            <label>Line 2 :</label>
            <input type="text" name="lineText" value="" class="lineText">
            </div>

           
            <div class="input-row">

            <div class="button-container">
            <div class="warning"></div>
            <button class="addLine">Add Another Line</button>

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>`;
        
            console.log(lineNumber);
        }
 
})();

//lineText addEventListener update object value
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  let self = e.target;//input field
 let lineTextValue = self.value;
 
 // has class .lineText
 if (hasClass(self, 'lineText')) {      

      //for each lineObject in LineArray 
       //lineArray.forEach(function(arrayObject) {
        
        //update lineObject HTMLelement.prototype
       Object.defineProperty(lineObject, 'lineText', {
   
            //update object value to event target value
         get: function() {        
               return this.lineTextValue;//how can I get the right lineObject object from the array when I update the input  
             },
          
          set: function(lineTextValue) {
            this.lineText = lineTextValue;//how can I aet the right lineObject object in the array when I update the input
          }          
       });
        //debugging
        //console.log('objectProperty = ' + arrayObject.lineText);
        console.log('this.lineText = ' + this.lineText);  
    console.log('Object.entries(lineObject) - ' + Object.entries(lineObject));
        //console.log('lineObject.lineText = '+ lineObject.lineText);
        //console.log('lineTextValue = '+ lineTextValue);
      //});
  };
});

let button = document.getElementById('test');
button.addEventListener( "click", testFunction );
function testFunction(){ 

 button.addEventListener( "click", testFunction );
  //console.log('Object.keys(lineObject) - '+ Object.keys(lineObject));
  //console.log('Reflect.ownKeys(lineObject) - ' + Reflect.ownKeys(lineObject));
  //console.log('Object.values - ' + Object.values(lineObject));
  //console.log('lineObject = '+ lineObject.lineText);
  
  //console.log('Object.entries(lineObject) - ' + Object.entries(lineObject));
  //console.log('Object.entries(lineObjectClone) - ' + Object.entries(lineObjectClone));
  
  //console.log('lineObjectClone.lineText = ' + lineObject.lineText);
  //console.log('lineObjectClone[1].lineText = ' + lineObjectClone.lineText);
  //console.log('lineArray[0] = ' + lineArray[0].lineText);
  console.log('lineArray = ' + lineArray);
  console.log('numberOfLines = ' + numberOfLines);
  for(let i = 0; i < numberOfLines; ++i ){
    console.log('lineArray[i].lineText = ' + lineArray[i].lineText)
  }
};

//does the element have the class specified?
function hasClass(elem, className) {
      return elem.classList.contains(className);
};
```

```html
<section>

  <button id="test">Test</button>
    
  <div class="lineNumber">
  <div class="accordion-title">
   <h3>Line</h3>
   
  </div>
  <div class="input-section" style="display: block;"> 
   <div class="input-row">

    <div class="input-container">
     <label>Line Text :</label>
     <input type="text" name="lineText" value="" class="lineText">
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="input-row">

    <div class="button-container">
     <div class="warning"></div>
     <button class="addLine">Add Another Line</button>   
    </div>
 </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
</section>
```

Comment: There are lots of existing frameworks for model binding, why are you reinventing the wheel here?

Comment: Learning exercise, cant get my head around the relationship and how to manipulate an object with a element this way. Want to understand the fundamentals.

Comment: This is a good answer to essentially the core of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483560/how-to-implement-dom-data-binding-in-javascript You should be able to suss out relationship with the child elements using querySelector and filter methods.  IMHO, not a bad place to use jQuery to make it easier.

Comment: @4m1r thanks will take a look now. Not interested in jquery as trying to learn the fundamentals. Update: I've already been through that post and while informative I was hoping for some input on a solution to my specific approach. Will take another look though.

Comment: hmm, would a onchange event listener work for you?

Comment: @HenriqueDonati I've got the onChange listener set up (keyPress) the issue is how to update the correct object in the array with the value. That's currently where I am up to with the fiddle.It creates the element and the object and detects the events, but it does not update the objects value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

The purpose of a closure is to capture variables from the containing function so those variables can be used later, after the containing function exits.

A simple example could look like this:

```
let data = {
    nameGenerator: 0
};

function addInput() {
    // generate a new name and property in data object
    let propertyName = String.fromCharCode("a".charCodeAt() + data.nameGenerator++);
    // initialize property value to its name
    data[propertyName] = propertyName;

    // add <div><input value="(property)"></div> to container
    let containerElement = document.getElementById("container");
    let lineElement = document.createElement("div");
    let inputElement = document.createElement("input");
    lineElement.appendChild(inputElement);
    containerElement.appendChild(lineElement);

    // initialize input value (note: this does not bind the two, just initializes)
    inputElement.value = data[propertyName];

    // create a closure that binds the property to the element
    inputElement.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
        // inside this function, propertyName and inputElement 
        // are "captured" in the closure
        data[propertyName] = inputElement.value;
    })
}
```

Note that the `propertyName` and `inputElement` variables are defined in the outer `addInput` function, but they are captured in the closure that is created when you assign the anonymous function as an event listener.

Here is a fiddle with a complete working example: https://jsfiddle.net/b3ta60cn/

Comment: Thanks will experiment with this for a bit and look into closures.